# How to modify a dataset's dataflow in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have created a data flow.

Then created a dataset that uses the dataflow as data source.

Then I tried editing the dataset to a point to a different dataflow, however there isnt an option to change to a different dataflow.

How to modify a dataset's dataflow in Power BI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The M code genderated when loading data from a Power BI Dataflow looks like this:

```
let
    Source = PowerBI.Dataflows(null),
    #"Long-Workspace-Id" = Source{[workspaceId="Long-Workspace-Id"]}[Data],
    #"Long-Dataflow-Id" = #"Long-Workspace-Id"{[dataflowId="Long-Dataflow-Id"]}[Data],
    #"Sample Data1" = #"Long-Dataflow-Id"{[entity="Sample Data"]}[Data]
in
    #"Sample Data1"
```

With ID values that look like this fake ID string: `68920386-482d-445e-9725-839065646dde`.

---

So, you just need to figure out the ID values for the dataflow you *do* want to connect to and swap them out.

One way to find these IDs would be to connect to the other dataflow in another Power BI instance and copy the values from the query editor in that one over to the original Power BI instance.

The IDs are also contained in the URL when you navigate to the dataflow within the workspace that it lives in. The URL looks like

```
https://app.powerbi.com/groups/long-workspace-id/dataflows/long-dataflow-id
```

Comment: Does this have to be done for each table?

Comment: All the ones you want to change that directly reference a dataflow, yes. If you think you'll do this frequently, you can set the IDs as parameters that each table references so that you only need to change IDs in one place going forward.

Comment: By "one place" I assume you mean in the pbix file's power query. Could I also set it via the dataset settings (parameters) in the power bi service?

Comment: I had the PBIX query editor in mind but it does look like this can be adjusted in the service too.